# python MySQL db and Cursor cannot execute INSERT INTO

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, cursor

In Python version 2.7.6

Pandas version 0.18.1

MySQL 5.7

```
import MySQLdb as dbapi
import sys
import csv
import os
import sys, getopt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
rows = df.apply(tuple, 1).unique().tolist()

db=dbapi.connect(host=dbServer,user=dbUser,passwd=dbPass)

cur=db.cursor()

for (CLIENT_ID,PROPERTY_ID,YEAR) in rows:

                INSERT_QUERY=("INSERT INTO {DATABASE}.TEST SELECT * FROM {DATABASE}_{CLIENT_ID}.TEST WHERE PROPERTY_ID = {PROPERTY_ID} AND YEAR = {YEAR};".format(
                CLIENT_ID=CLIENT_ID,
                PROPERTY_ID=PROPERTY_ID,
                YEAR=YEAR,
                DATABASE=DATABASE
             ))

                print INSERT_QUERY
                cur.execute(INSERT_QUERY)
                db.query(INSERT_QUERY)
```

This will print out the query I am looking for, however, without successfully returning the results of INSERT INTO when I checked the results in MySQL

```
INSERT INTO test.TEST SELECT * FROM test_1.TEST WHERE PROPERTY_ID = 1 AND YEAR = 2015;
```

However, if I just copy and paste this MySQL query into MySQL GUI, it will execute without any problem.  Could any guru enlighten?

I also tried the following

```
cur.execute(INSERT_QUERY, multi=True)
```

Returns an error

```
TypeError: execute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'multi'
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is we need to use "from mysql.connector" and a db.commit().  Here is a good example

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/python-mysql-insert/

```
import MySQLdb as dbapi
import mysql.connector
import sys
import csv
import os
import sys, getopt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
rows = df.apply(tuple, 1).unique().tolist()

db=dbapi.connect(host=dbServer,user=dbUser,passwd=dbPass)

cur=db.cursor()

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host=dbServer,user=dbUser,port=dbPort,password=dbPass)

cursor=conn.cursor()

for (CLIENT_ID,PROPERTY_ID,YEAR) in rows:

                INSERT_QUERY=("INSERT INTO {DATABASE}.TEST SELECT * FROM {DATABASE}_{CLIENT_ID}.TEST WHERE PROPERTY_ID = {PROPERTY_ID} AND YEAR = {YEAR};".format(
                CLIENT_ID=CLIENT_ID,
                PROPERTY_ID=PROPERTY_ID,
                YEAR=YEAR,
                DATABASE=DATABASE
             ))

                print INSERT_QUERY
                cursor.execute(INSERT_QUERY)
                conn.commit()
```

Only by having the commit, the database/ table changes will be accepted

Answer (score 0):

I was using mysql-connector pool, trying to insert a new row into a table, and got the same problem. The version info: mysql-8, python3.7.
The solution is to add connection.commit at last even you didn't start transaction.